# How to achieve the same readability from unix to windows

Tags: linux, unix, awk, printf, solaris

in any directory in UNIX that has some files, please give the below command

```
ls -lrt | awk '{printf "%-55s%-5s%-5s%-10s%-15s\n", $9,$6,$7,$8,$5}'
```

the output that you see will look formatted or easily readable/understandable

I capture this commands output in a file and send that as an email.

```
ls -lrt | awk '{printf "%-55s%-5s%-5s%-10s%-15s\n", $9,$6,$7,$8,$5}' > $TMP_DIR/test.dat
mail -s "FILES CHECK " someone@gmail.com < $TMP_DIR/test.dat
```

But in the email, the order that we see in UNIX is missing.
Those with bigger file-names and those with smaller file-names combined make the look scrambled.
Please let me know how to achieve the same readability in windows also.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the content of the file looks the way you want it to, the problem is in how your email viewing application shows the message.  Specifically, many email clients will render a "plain text" message using "HTML" rules, which collapse multiple spaces into one, or use variable-width fonts instead of the fixed-width ones you're used to in your terminal.  You can overcome some of this by simply writing HTML tags in your email:

```
echo '<html><body><pre>' > $TMP_DIR/test.dat
ls -lrt | awk '...' >> $TMP_DIR/test.dat
echo '</pre></body></html>' >> $TMP_DIR/test.dat
mail -a "Content-type: text/html" -s "FILES CHECK " someone@example.com < $TMP_DIR/test.dat
```

Now your message may be rendered (in HTML-capable applications) the way you want, with a fixed-width font, thanks to the "pre" formatting tag.

You could also send the message with the "rich text" MIME type, and enclose the contents in `<fixed>` and `</fixed>` tags.

Comment: when I use the below
echo '<html><body><pre>' > $TMP_DIR/test.dat
ls -lrt | awk '{printf "%-55s%-5s%-5s%-10s%-15s\n", $9,$6,$7,$8,$5}' >> $TMP_DIR/test.dat
echo '</pre></body></html>' >> $TMP_DIR/test.dat
mail -s "FILES CHECK " someone@gmail.com < $TMP_DIR/test.dat

it just adds <html><body><pre> & </pre></body></html> at the end
rest of the data is same and readability is not acheived

Comment: Try adding `-a "Content-type: text/html"` to your `mail` command.  This should convince your mail client to display as HTML.